# Play a .mov file in existing VLC media player window using command line

Tags: vlc-media-player, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to play a .mov file using VLC media player (2.1.4) command line, but I want it to join the existing VLC media player window each time.

It seems like in older versions there was a command-line option, --one-, instance, but that's not available any more. It seems like it got deprecated.

Is there a new way of doing this?

Comment: someone suggested in the settings choosing "allow only one instance" but that doesn't seem to be a setting in my version either. 2.1.4 seems to be the latest version of vlc.

Comment: The option "allow only one instance" [is still there](http://i.imgur.com/qC2Sduk.png). I downloaded [2.1.4](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/2.1.4/win64/) and double checked it. Once this setting is activated, you don't need any additional command line parameters. just start some videos via command line and they will all run in a single instance

Answer (score 2):

According to the VLC documentation those parameters still exist, but can be overridden in the playlist dialog box.  i.e. your settings may have been preventing `--one-instance` from working properly.  Please make sure your settings are correct.  See the screen shot below for the correct settings if VLC is already launched.

[image: VLC screen capture]

You should also look into the following command line parameters:

```
     --one-instance, --no-one-instance
                                 Allow only one running instance (default
                                 disabled)
          Allowing only one running instance of VLC can sometimes be useful,
          for example if you associated VLC with some media types and you don't
          want a new instance of VLC to be opened each time you open a file in
          your file manager. This option will allow you to play the file with
          the already running instance or enqueue it. (default disabled)
      --started-from-file, --no-started-from-file
                                 VLC is started from file association (default
                                 disabled)
          Tell VLC that it is being launched due to a file association in the
          OS (default disabled)
      --one-instance-when-started-from-file, --no-one-instance-when-started-from-file
                                 Use only one instance when started from file
                                 manager (default enabled)
          Use only one instance when started from file manager (default enabled)
      --playlist-enqueue, --no-playlist-enqueue
                                 Enqueue items into playlist in one instance
                                 mode (default disabled)
          When using the one instance only option, enqueue items to playlist
          and keep playing current item. (default disabled)
```

Comment: Hmmm it seems like neither of these options is available on the mac version - I didn't realise that they would be different.